# Custom cocoapods xcodeproj file

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

By default a CocoaPods installation makes Pods/Pods.xcodeproj. Is there a way I can set it to be called something else, like Pods/MyCustomPods.xcodeproj?

The scenario is that I have a workspace that contains multiple projects in multiple directories, and two of the projects there use CocoaPods. And not only would it then be confusing with two projects named Pods, but Xcode can't cope well with that and confuses the two projects.

Cheers

Nik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach with multiple Pods projects was incorrect. In this case, rather make a .xcorkspace and then point your Podfile at it

```
workspace 'MyCustom.xcworkspace'
```

then in each of your targets, point at the respective .xcodeproj:

```
target 'A' do
  xcodeproj 'A.xcodeproj'
  pod 'SamplePod'
end

target 'B' do
  xcodeproj 'B.xcodeproj'
  pod 'SamplePod'
  pod 'OtherPod'
end
```

This works really well :-)